# Components.interfaces.nsIProcess truncates a URL argument which contains "&"

Tags: javascript, windows, firefox

I have javascript code (windows/firefox) which launches a URL using

```
    var process = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/process/util;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIProcess);
```

The command is cmd /c start MYURL

This works for most cases, except when the URL contains an &, such as

http://www.google.com/search?q=Robert+Doisneau&ct=doisneau12-hp&oi=ddle
gets truncated to
http://www.google.com/search?q=Robert+Doisneau

From a command line the same thing happens, but putting quotes around the URL solves the problem.

So, I put quotes around my URL in my javascript, but then windows produces this error when using double quotes:

> Windows cannot find
>   '\http://www.google.com/search?q=Robert+Doisneau&ct=doisneau12-hp&oi=ddle\'.
>   Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again.

What is the nsIProcess doing differently when I pass the URL in quotes, and how can I avoid that? Or how can I re-form my URL so that it is not truncated at the &?  I cannot replace the & with %26, as it isn't part of the text, it is used to pass the parameters.

Answer (score 2):

I think I know what is happening. CMD can take several commands as an argument with each separated by the & character and the entire list enclosed in quotes.

The format for multiple arguments is CMD /c "arg & arg & arg". Thus & is interpreted as the start of a new argument.

The escape character in CMD arguments is ^. So you need to run:

```
CMD /C "START http://www.google.com/search?q=Robert+Doisneau^&ct=doisneau12-hp^&oi=ddle"
```

Note that the quote starts before START and ends after the url. That whole part is one argument passed to CMD. I'm not sure off hand if nsIProcess auto-quotes arguments, so you many need to experiment with that.

Comment: Thank you @James!  That was exactly what I needed to fix this.  It had me stumped all weekend.  I never saw the info about the & in any of the docs I managed to find.

Comment: @MarybethMarkland if this is the answer to your question, please tick "v" next to it so it is marked as solved.

Answer (score 0):

It's strange, as I can't get it working from command line as you mentioned:

- Without adding anything, I get truncated URL
- When I add double quotes in command line around the URLs, I simply get new *command line window* opened.
- When I add single quotes (apostrophe), I get the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to launch the URL via `nsIProcess`? Just load the URL in a browser tab, and if Firefox doesn't understand it then it will automatically prompt to invoke the system handler for that protocol.